# independent actions to map overlays -xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, action, overlay

how can I add independent actions to map overlays? see my code for example: I am not sure if I should use a loop or an if statement. And if I use If statement how it should be? thank you in advance..

```
- (void)configureOverlay {
if (self.location) {
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];        
    [self.mapView removeOverlays:[self.mapView overlays]];

    radiusSmall = 100;

        circleOverlaySmall *overlaysmall = [[circleOverlaySmall alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.location.coordinate radius:radiusSmall];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:overlaysmall];
    [self updateSmall]; <--this action called

            CircleOverlay *overlay = [[CircleOverlay alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.location.coordinate radius:self.radius];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:overlay];

    GeoQueryAnnotation *annotation = [[GeoQueryAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.location.coordinate radius:self.radius];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    [self updateLocations]; <--this action called

}
}
```

Comment: what are the actions you want to perform? you have used if statement on a map condition already, for update location and update small you can use IF similarly.. please specify the action you want to perform more clearly in order to better answers..

Answer (score 0):

just drag the [self uploadSmall]; below the [self updateLocations];